# gulp notification dependent on task completion without .pipe

Tags: javascript, notifications, gulp, node-notifier

I know I can use [node-notifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781981/calling-gulp-notify-without-using-pipe) but is there a better way to set up a notification which is dependent on a task being complete (and which does not use .pipe)

The below works but is there a way to achieve this within a single task?

```
// Perform data task
gulp.task('imgData1', function() { 
  imageExport.record({
    path: path.images_src,
    output: path.images_data,
    template: 'custom.hbs',
    breakpointDelimiter: '--'
  })
});

// Perform notification task 
gulp.task('imgData2', ['imgData1'], function() {
  notifier.notify({
  'title': 'My notification',
  'message': 'Data task complete!'
});
});

// Perform data task then the notification task 
gulp.task('imgData', ['imgData2']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image-size-export` [accepts a callback](https://github.com/Sebastian-Fitzner/image-size-export/blob/e13dba4/lib/imagesizeExport.js#L167) that is invoked when `imageExport.record()` has finished. Simply run `notifier.notify()` in that callback:

```
gulp.task('imgData', function() { 
  imageExport.record({
    path: path.images_src,
    output: path.images_data,
    template: 'custom.hbs',
    breakpointDelimiter: '--'
  }, function() {
     notifier.notify({
       'title': 'My notification',
       'message': 'Data task complete!'
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. I did give that a go but was getting an error re `var tpl = template.toString();` -  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`. Will take another look.

Comment: That's [this line](https://github.com/Sebastian-Fitzner/image-size-export/blob/e13dba47c3f9f52851e4f904611a26e6d7955cff/lib/imagesizeExport.js#L148). Probably means the `custom.hbs` file cannot be read for some reason (wrong path?).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. yes exactly. I was being an eedyat and not updated my file paths correctly. Working perfectly now. Thanks for your help!